# MongoDB filtering string in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

In one of my schemas (called Question) in mongodb, I have an array defined which consists of strings: e.g.

> tags = ['6.01', '6.02', '8.01']

I want to be able to filter through the Questions and find any Question which has a tag starting with '6'. So for example, if we have the following Questions and their associated tags:

**Question 1:**

> tags = ['6.01', '6.02', '8.01']

**Question 2:**

> tags = ['9.01', '7.012', '10.11']

**Question 3:**

> tags = ['7.014', '6.UA', '21.012']

The query should return Question 1 and 3 because they each have at least one tag that starts with a '6'

I think I should use regex, something like `^+'6'`, but I am not sure how to query in `mongodb`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.questions.find({tags: /^6/})
```

Mind you, this could be pretty slow if your collection is large. You may want to add an index on tags as well to speed this up: `db.questions.createIndex({tags: 1})`.

Comment: Just a quick question, for the regex, if I just put /^6/, will it automatically recognize that it is searching for a string? Say if I wanted to look for "Social" in the tags, would I do /^Social/ ? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, regex' always operate on strings, and yes your example is correct.